# Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot load script"

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to render an pdf file with pdf.js. I use npm to install pdfjs-dist. My pdf-view.js file:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =  import('/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js');
pdfjsLib.getDocument( pdfUrl).promise.then(function (pdf_doc) {
        
        myState.pdf = pdf_doc;
        showMultiPages(); //render pdf page
       // URL.revokeObjectURL(objURL);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

The errors  i get: Setting up fake worker failed: "Cannot load script at:...."
And in console:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: "

I have tried to remove the "import" function:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

use import:

```
import pdfjsWorker from "/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry.js";
```

but i have errors: net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Can someone please tell me what i did wrong?